# Order by bigint myisam is not ordered. Why?

Tags: mariadb, myisam, bigint

I had to use bigint instead of regular int. After creating the new table it bahaves unusual. See details below.

```
MariaDB [user]> select * from dmn_base2 ORDER BY id DESC limit 4;
+------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------+
| id         | domain                | base           | tld_id |
+------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------+
| 1975224411 | bank-3dsecure.com     | bank-3dsecure  |      4 |
|  466015797 | bank-365.se           | bank-365       |    378 |
| 1711908528 | bank-2projects.online | bank-2projects |     20 |
|   27739599 | bank-2580.com         | bank-2580      |      4 |
+------------+-----------------------+----------------+--------+
   ^----this is unusual
```

It uses index:

```
MariaDB [user]> explain select * from dmn_base2 ORDER BY id DESC limit 4;
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | dmn_base2 | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    4 |       |
+------+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------+
```

Structure of the table:

```
MariaDB [user]> show columns from dmn_base2;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| domain | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| base   | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| tld_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+


MariaDB [capturesipbee]> SHOW CREATE TABLE dmn_base2;
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dmn_base2 | CREATE TABLE `dmn_base2` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `base` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `tld_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `domain` (`domain`),
  KEY `base` (`base`),
  KEY `tld_id` (`tld_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Indexes:

```
MariaDB [user]> show indexes from dmn_base2;
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| dmn_base2 |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |   460592774 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dmn_base2 |          0 | domain   |            1 | domain      | A         |   460592774 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dmn_base2 |          1 | base     |            1 | base        | A         |   460592774 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| dmn_base2 |          1 | tld_id   |            1 | tld_id      | A         |        1967 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

query does not finished, killing has no effect after 5 hours

```
+------+-------+-----------+----+---------+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id   | User  | Host      | db | Command | Time  | State        | Info                                                      | Progress |
+------+-------+-----------+----+---------+-------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|   36 | root  | localhost | db | Killed  | 21107 | Sending data | select * from dmn_base2 ORDER BY id DESC limit 5          |    0.000 |
```

<del>my guess is: broken index file?</del>

I have copied the database to other device. The same query works as expected.

```
mysql> select * from dmn_base order by id desc limit 4;
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
| id         | domain               | base              | tld_id |
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
| 2147483647 | naturleckerlies.de   | naturleckerlies   |    921 |
| 2147475178 | meinlohne.de         | meinlohne         |    921 |
| 2147471022 | mamis-zeit.de        | mamis-zeit        |    921 |
| 2147456303 | kinderpact-berlin.de | kinderpact-berlin |    921 |
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: 'my guess is: broken index file?' - why not fix t and see?

Comment: @P.Salmon I will do of course

Comment: @P.Salmon fixing index did not solved the problem

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE dmn_base2`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Recommend changing to InnoDB -- MyISAM, not InnoDB, can get "broken indexes"

Comment: @RickJames question updated, I use MyISAM for multiple reason: faster data import from csv, index using myisamchk, fulltextsearch, easy db file portablity

Comment: @AlexSzücs - Fulltext was added to InnoDB in 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update MariaDB. (10.1->10-6)

As I use Plesk I refer to this articles:

- [Which MariaDB versions are supported by Plesk?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360013751840-Which-MariaDB-versions-are-supported-by-Plesk-)
- [Upgrade guide](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213403429)